# What is the the output of the following C programme?

Tags: c, pointers

I don't know what the compilar is doing with `++*p;`

Can anyone explain me pictorically what is going on inside the memory in this code?

```
int main()
{
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
    int *p;
    p=arr;
    ++*p;
    printf("%d",*p);
}
```

Comment: you should be able to work that out from a basic tutorial....

Comment: can anyone pictorically dipict it

Comment: Oops!
@krishnaChandra : Read Intrepidd's answer, it should be easy to understand :)

Comment: at least not expecting downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making up the actual memory addresses and using "ma" for memory address

at memory address starting at 1000 we have 4 continuous 4-byte (sizeof(int) = 4) slots.
  each slot contains the integer value given in the array initializer:

```
  arr
  ma1000 ... ma1015
  _____________________
  |   1|   2|   3|   4|   
  _____________________
```

arr gives the starting address of the 4 int slots and how many there are.
  p holds the address of an integer and refers to one 8-byte slot in memory (assuming we are on a *64-bit system* where pointers are 8 bytes - 64 address bits/8bits-per-byte) at location 2000. 
  After the statement p = arr, p holds the address 1000

```
  p                     *p or arr[0]
  ma2000 .. ma2007      ma1000 .. ma1003
  __________            ________
  |    1000|            |    1 |
  __________            ________
```

*p gives the value at the memory address pointed to by p. p holds  memory address 1000 and memory address 1000 contains 1, thus *p results in 1.

++*p says to increment the value of the int "pointed to" by p. p holds memory address 1000 which holds the value 1. The value at address 1000 then goes from 1 to 2

```
 arr
 ma1000 ... ma1015
 _____________________
 |   2|   2|   3|   4|   
 _____________________
```

printf then prints the int value at the address "pointed to" by p, which is 2.

```
  p                     *p or arr[0]

  ma2000 .. ma2007       ma1000 .. ma1003
  ___________           ___________
  |     1000|           |        2|
  ___________           ___________
```

Comment: The arr's address has to be 1016 at last instead of 1015

Comment: @krishnaChandra  if it went from 1000 to 1016 that would make it 17 bytes long. That doesn't sound right.

Comment: ya i got it......can you have any link the will pictorically describes the concepts of pointers as you did above

Comment: @krishnaChandra They have material here: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/,  which includes a video.

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be 2

The reason is ++*p is is actually incrementing the first member in the array by 1.

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing the first element in that array by creating another int pointer `p` that points to the element. The line

```
 ++*p
```

increments the value of the object pointed to by p - in this case it is the first element in the array.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But it's not 'creating another'. It's modifying it in-place.

Comment: @Joe I didnt say that I say that he is creating ANOTHER `int *` which he uses to point to that element and changing it via that.

Comment: Like I said, I didn't downvote. But the word 'creating' could be misleading.

Comment: @mathematician1975 Apologies, I must've been confused. Read your answer again and it seems fine to me. Will undo and upvote if you edit your answer ;)

Comment: @mathematician1975 : now seem to be in order

Answer (score 1):

Let's take this line :

```
++*p
```

This will first dereference the p pointer, so access arr[0], then increment it.

if you print arr[0] now, it will be 2.

Then you print *p that is the same as printing arr[0], it equals 2.

Try replacing the first element by 41, your code will print 42.

Comment: what i was thinking coz indirection and preincrement have same priorities so evalution order is right to left...first *p is evaluted and the answer is 1 .now it becomes ++1 ......after it it becomes 2 ..what sucks me where the 2 will be stored?

Comment: Try this, ++*p can be seen as :

*p = *p +1

Answer (score 1):

When you have a pointer `int *p`, then `p` means "the memory address `p` points to and `*p` means "the contents of the memory address where `p` points to". `++` means pre-increment, which means increase the value by 1. Since the associativity of unary operators such as `*` and `++`(prefix operators) is right-to-left, and `*` is closer to `p` than `++` when traversed right-to-left, `*` operates before `++`. Therefore `++*p` means "increment the value pointed to by `p`", not "increment `p` then get the value". It is clearer to write `++(*p)`, but it means the same thing.

The thing to understand is the difference between "increment the pointer", which means point to another value (e.g. `++p`) and "increment the value that the pointer points to" (e.g. `++*p`).

You can work this out, but that is all the information you need to understand it.

Comment: Small nitpick. `*` doesn't have a higher precedence than `++`. In fact its the other way round. The reason that dereferencing is taking place before the increment here is due to the associativity of the operators

Comment: what i was thinking coz indirection and preincrement have same priorities so evalution order is right to left...first *p is evaluted and the answer is 1 .now it becomes ++1 ......after it it becomes 2 ..what sucks me where the 2 will be stored?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic concept in understanding of pointers.

```
p = arr ;
```

The above code will make the pointer " p " to point towards what the " arr " is pointing to. " arr " itself is pointing to the 1st element.

```
*arr = *(arr + 0) = arr[0] = 1
*(arr + 1) = arr[1] = 2
*(arr + 2) = arr[2] = 3
```

and so on...
So now when you do `++(*arr) that means ++(1) = 2`

As `p = arr`, you can do the remaining replacement and math.